# Объявление прототипа шаблонной функции с++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

У меня имеется реализация шаблонной функции в одном файле, каким образом я могу объявить прототип этой функции, чтобы она стала доступна в текущем файле?

Более точно: зачем может потребоваться декларация шаблонной функции без тела, такая как `template<typename T> T inc(const T&);`?

Comment: дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1265176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8?noredirect=1

Comment: @user7860670, Ваша ссылка немножко мимо ведет. Поправьте её, пожалуйста :-).

Comment: @user7860670, я создал новый вопрос, потому что на тот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1265176/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8?noredirect=1), мне кинули дубликат, за последнюю строчку где я описал ошибку, хотя вопрос заключался абсолютно в  другом, а ответа на него я так и не получил

Comment: На то он и шаблон, что должен включаться целиком. Его тела не существует, он подставляется в конкретные места где используется.

Comment: Ну так правильно, в дубликате предыдущего вопроса как раз раскрывается, почему в такой ситуации бестолку делать прототип шаблонной функции. @Vladimir Не, ссылка правильная.

Comment: @nevilad, спасибо. Получается что шаблонные функции должны включаться в сам заголовочный файл. И еще вопрос, но почему компилятор допускает такую запись `template <class T> T foo(T a)`, если она бесполезна?

Comment: @user7860670, извините не досмотрел, виноват

Comment: Да, если предполагается что шаблон будут использовать во многих файлах, их целиком добавляют в заголовочный файл. Про почему компилятор допускает запись не совсем понял. Это forward-определение?

Comment: @user7860670, ссылка ведет на страницу 404 - поэтому я и написал.

Comment: @nevilad, да, почему допускается forward-определение если оно бесполезно.

Comment: Что вы называете "реализацией шаблонной функции"? Если строку вида `template<typename T> T inc(const T arg) { return arg+1; }` -- то это НЕ реализация. Реализацию компилятор сгенерирует в тот момент, когда вы шаблоном воспользуетесь, напишете `int x = 1; auto y = inc(x);` либо определите как `template float int(const float arg);`. Или же вы говорите про специализацию `template<> int inc(const int x) { return x-1;}`? Уточните ваш вопрос.

Comment: @PakUula, я имею ввиду, что компилятор почему-то допускает такую запись `template <typename T> T inc(const T arg);` хотя она бесполезна.

Comment: Одни шаблоны могут использовать другие шаблоны. Здесь forward-определение шаблона может пригодиться.

Comment: @nevilad, извиняюсь за тупость, а не могли бы вы привести примеры, использования шаблонов другими шаблонами, а то не совсем понимаю как это.

Comment: @Vladimir, потому что по ней вопрос этого же автора и он решил его удалить.

Comment: template<typename Type> class templClass;

template<typename Type> class templClass2
{
  templClass<Type> member_;
public:
  Type func(const char c) { return member_.func(); }
};

template<typename Type> class templClass
{
  Type member_;
public:
  Type func(const char c) { return member_; }
};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по комментариям, ТС интересуется, почему C++ дозволяет декларацию шаблона функции без тела.

Когда у шаблона тело есть, то всё понятно. В момент первого использования шаблона компилятор сгенерирует для него тело. Если же в шаблоне тела нет, то что будет?

Ответ: компилятор ничего не сгенерирует. Он запомнит точку, в которой использовался шаблон, и на этапе линковки постарается найти для него тело с нужной сигнатурой. Тело может быть получено либо через инстанциацию полного шаблона, либо через специализацию неполного.

Пример.

Заголовочный файл `t.hpp`:

```cpp
template<typename T> T F(const T x); // { return x+1; }
template<typename T> T G(const T x); // { return 2*x; }
```

Файл `b.cpp` с телами функций:

```cpp
#include "t.hpp"

template<typename T> T G(const T x) { return 2*x; }

// Специализация шаблона для случая int F<int>(cont int)
template<> int F(const int x) { return x - 1; }

static int stub() {
        int x = 10;
        return G(x); // Инстанциируется шаблон для случая int G<int>(const int)
}
```

В файле `a.cpp` оба шаблона видны без тела. Но компилятор сругается на другое.

```
#include "t.hpp"

int main() {
        int x = 10;
        auto y = F(x); // int F<int>(const int) -- специализация в b.cpp
        auto z = G(y);  // int G<int>(const int) -- инстанциация в b.cpp
        // Ошибка линковки: нет тела для double F<double>(const double)
        return z + F(1.0);
}
```

Вывод команды `g++ -o some.exe a.cpp b.cpp`:

```
/tmp/ccu0YKts.o: In function `main':
a.cpp:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `double F<double>(double)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Во время линковки компилятор найдёт тело F из специализации в `b.cpp`, тело `G<int>` из инстанциации в `b.cpp`, а тело `G<double>` не найдёт, ибо этот шаблон нигде ни использовался, ни инстанциировался.

ИМХО, шаблон без тела - это хождение по граблям, стреляющим разрывным патроном прямо в пятку, но логике стандарта не противоречит.

Comment: VS2017 с `/std:c++latest` не находит две функции (`unresolved external symbol`) - `int __cdecl G<int>(int)` и `double __cdecl F<double>(double)`. Так что не стоит рассчитывать на то, что определения без тела всегда будут работать.

Comment: @nevilad видимо VS2017 проигнорировал неиспользуемую статическую функцию, поэтому инстанциацию не произвёл. Как бы то ни было, шаблоны без тела - это выстрелы себе в пятку.